# Tags for storm control

Tags: feature-request, tags, interesting-tags

I'm coming from Serverfault I just opened my first question here on Network Engineering.

Since we're in beta, I would like to recommend the tag "storm-control", and since I don't have 300 reputation here, I'm asking on the meta.

The thread that I've just opened is this one: [Cisco: broadcast and multicast storm control on distribution switches](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20368/cisco-broadcast-and-multicast-storm-control-on-distribution-switches)

And I was really surprised that here we don't have tags for storm-control.

Comment: Welcome! And thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we are out of beta, we are still a relatively new community, so I am sure we are missing tags. I have added the requested tag for you.